# Feynman Lectures for a newcomer

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

I'm a senior philosophy/economics undergrad and I'm recently finding myself very interested in physics. For several reasons, I'm not able to take physics courses in college, but I wanted to introduce myself to the "corpus" of the undergrad physics. I'm willing to invest time and have taken several math courses (up to measure theory, though I missed Complex Analysis) so I don't think the math would be a problem, but... I literally don't know any physics (I mean, beyond the highschool curriculum, which is not saying much in my home country).

Can I use The Feynman Lectures for my purpose? Apparently, it's a very well structured corpus so it seems perfect, but I've heard it requieres to have some background in physics to really learn from it, and I really don't have any. Is that true?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47109/discussion-on-question-by-bolano-feynman-lectures-for-a-newcomer).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your personality, I think you would be very well placed to read the Feynman lectures and they would be an excellent beginning. Beware, though, of seeking "Bibles"- seek a few references and read them all at a relaxed rate at the same time. Seek more specialized, but broad, references for the "pillar" subjects as well. [Alonso and Finn, "Fundamental University Physics"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006BNQDG) (the multi volume edition, rather than the shortened, all-in-one tome called "Physics") may work for you as a backup. Measure theory is well beyond the mathematical sophistication you will need to understand Feynman's lectures. Feynman, notwithstanding his well kenned disdain for "Philozofers" and his infamous behest to "shut up and calculate[without understanding]", shows in his thinking and teaching style he is quite the philosopher himself: always on the lookout for meaning in this work. I find philosophy - particularly ontology and epistemology - fascinating and so I can tentatively recommend this book to someone like the impression I get of you from your short summary.

Complex analysis - if by that you mean the theory of holomorphic functions - is not needed to understand this work - Feynman makes one, cryptic reference to the Cauchy Riemann relationships in the whole work without naming them, asking the reader to ask the mathematicians for themselves so that the reader will have something interesting to do in maths course and lest mathematical teaching deprived of the CR relationships should become a "rather boring subject"!! I find mathematics highly interesting BTW! Pretty much all of the complex number theory you will need is covered by Feynman himself in the ["Algebra" chapter of volume 1](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_22.html).

Comment: **Landau and Lifschitz, "A Course of Theoretical Physics" may work for you as a backup.** - that you are seriously recommending what are graduate level texts as introductory texts for someone who is a complete beginner to physics is utterly bizarre.

Comment: @SuzuHirose The OP's background is highly unusual - he has a great deal of relevant background. Also, I find L&L to be highly "sporadic" in level - there were bits that I could easily read and follow in my freshman year, and others that I didn't understand until I was 40. That many texts are like this is one of the reasons that several parallel texts can be helpful

Comment: For the second time *ever* on S.E I am upvoting *and* emphasizing a comment, again by  @SuzuHirose  .  And both of those times are today, on this page.  Landau and Lifschitz is difficult even if you have a PhD.  This is a bizarre suggestion.

Comment: Only one single answer I can agree with; thanks @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance; +1. I don't know why the other answers think Feynman is not good for a beginner. Well, here I am who learned physics literally from Feynman's Vol II and Vol III. While they are not extraordinary, they are different in the style of presentation; the lucid explanation and a innovative approach to deal with respective contents; he explained base states and operators with Stern-Garlech filters - that is insanely one of the brilliant things in his lectures. They are definitely accessible to undergrads.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 Yes, I loved the Stern-Gerlach filters too.

Comment: @garyp Actually sorry, my bad. I realize that I'm getting Landau and Lifschitz mixed up in my mind with [this one (the multi-volume version "Fundamental University Physics", not the all-in-one tome "Physics" )](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0006BNQDG/ref=pd_sbs_14_t_0?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=SP1DEF6F5QWW8P6CNBG7) by Alonso and Finn; I don't have either of them in my bookshelf and for me the thoughts of both L&L and A&F are rather near to one another because for some reason I see the exact same shade of blue when I think of either of them.

Comment: @SuzuHirose See my comment to garyp: I realize I was getting a little confused. The correct name may seem a little less bizarre to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Indeed, those things about Feynman makes me want to study from The Lectures, and I think you made a more or less accurate impression of me (though I'm more interested in philosophy of sciences and, to some extent, epistemology, as I find today's research in ontology quite far from what it was intended to be "originally"). Unfortunately, the other answers who make the exact opposite points make me hesitate. Did you learn the basics from the lectures or know someone who has? I'm very interested in @MAFIA36790 experience also, if you could extend a bit your answer I'd appreciate it

Comment: @Bolaño, If you want to discuss things, then you can come to our chatroom, [The h Bar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).

Comment: @Bolaño  It's actually very hard for me to say. My background is engineering, then mathematics when I learnt that the former didn't float my boat and the latter was where I wanted to be. I learnt physics piecemeal over a long time as a professional and as required in my work. QM is a good example here: I tried to learn it and found it infuriating because I easily had the mathematical background to grasp it (the concepts - Lie group theory, representations, linear algebra and so forth were all well wonted to me) and yet the equations meant nothing to me even though they were all familiar....

Comment: @Bolaño Then I came upon the Feynman lectures and found that his emphasis on physical insight was just what I needed. I also found that discussion of history is very helpful (as indeed I also found studying many mathematics subjects e.g. topology) - you see how the ideas don't come out of nowhere and that many dead ends were followed before the textbook notion is born. This helps you to be comfortable with being bewildered -you come to understand that this is an altogether normal feeling and indeed to some degree it is essential because it bespeaks an active and strenuous subconscious learning

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance   [sigh of relief]   :)

Answer (score 3):

The Feynman lectures is an extremely poor choice for a newcomer to physics. You will just end up confused.

"University physics" by Zemansky and Sears (any edition will do, even the old ones you can pick up for a few dollars) is a really excellent introduction to physics.

A **newcomer to physics cannot possibly learn physics from the Feynman lectures on physics**, the proposition is ridiculous. Most of the elementary explanations needed are completely missing from the book, there are no exercises except for some crappy typewriter-written things in a separate volume, and Feynman invariably takes an "alternative path" to doing things, somewhat like someone climbing up a mountain while walking on their hands.

Recommending the Feynman lectures as the main text to a complete newcomer to physics is myopic and absurd. I can open the Feynman lectures at random and find, on basically every page, a place where Feynman assumes some background knowledge or another.

Comment: I disagree (though I didn't downvote). I believe OP is more interested in how physicists think, rather than how to do calculations in physics.

Comment: **I literally don't know any physics** - OP. Are you serious? There is just no way that Feynman lectures are a good choice for this person.

Comment: If the OP is interested in how physicists think, I would highly recommend "Fear of Physics" by Lawrence Krauss. I love that book.

Comment: Even when he/she says "don't know any physics", they're not aware that their extant background is highly relevant and therefore I highly suspect they're a great deal more capable than they may think.

Comment: There are parts of *The Feynman Lectures* which are readable by and helpful for anyone. The introduction in which he talks about his one sentence for pass through the fall of civilization and *why* he would choose that is brilliant. But the set as a whole it pitched to people who either have some previous experience or at least are surrounded by others with a passionate interest in the subject who can help them along. The cautionary note in this answer is not unwarranted.

Comment: I agree with this answer 100%.  There's a cult around Feynman's book.  It's hip and cool to get on board and call it the greatest thing since sliced bread.

Comment: I was wondering, though, if the math background I've got can make me start on higher level textbooks so I don't have to go through thousands of pages and several books just to get where I want to be (explained in a comment to Shing's answer). If not, does that mean -taking it to the extreme, of course- that a math PhD who hasn't taken any physics college course should start learning from the same book than a HS graduate? (and follow the same "textbook-path" afterwards?).

Comment: @Bolaño - you could always borrow the Feynman books from a library and see how you find them. They don't feature explanations of many of the more basic concepts, and they contain no exercises at all. They're an incredibly poor choice for a complete novice. Not that they are bad books or anything, just they are not suited for a beginner. The University Physics books I mentioned are extremely easy to understand, have many exercises, and explain all the basics in great detail. Anyway it seems like I'm repeating myself all over again here.